# How do you divide a number stored in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

i was expecting that the code executed the command of height divided by weight.(p.s i only recently started learning how to code)

Comment: `cm` is the name of the function, in the print statements you should use `height`  which is the parameter.  `print(height/weight)`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid sending screenshots of your code and errors, use code blocks instead. Maybe also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have advice on writing great questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `cm()` takes the argument `height`, so if you want to divide height by weight, each of your print statements should use the `height` parameter:

```
def cm(height):
    print(height/weight)
    print(height/weight1)
    print(height/weight2)
```